# append results of loop into numeric vector

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to create a numeric vector with the results of a loop such as

```
> for (i in 1:5) print(i+1)
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
```

It seems strange that the same expression without 'print' returns nothing

```
> for (i in 1:5) i+1
>
```

Does anyone have an explanation/solution?

Comment: What numeric vector are you attempting to create?

Comment: i+1 is just for illustrative purposes. I have a more complex function that returns numbers, and I want the results to come in a vector, as in test <- numeric(8); for(i in 1:8){test[i] <- myfunction(i)}

Comment: Ok, I've added a `sapply` example to my answer. It pays to have a reproducible example of your problem. As your question stands it appears very basic, and we SO users would have to assume that you weren't asking a very basic question.

Comment: @dmvianna - please de-accept my answer and move it to mnel. My hastily added answer is not really good practice and i'd hate to encourage future readers to use it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is standard behaiviour -- when you say you want to create a numeric vector, 
 `print` will not do that

The expression in a for loop is an argument to the primitive function `for`

From `` ?`for` `` in the value section

> for, while and repeat return NULL invisibly. for sets var to the last
>   used element of seq, or to NULL if it was of length zero.

`print` prints the results to the console.

```
for(i in 1:5) i + 1
```

merely calculates `i + 1` for each iteration and returns nothing

If you want to assign something then assign it using `<-`, or less advisably `assign`

---

You can avoid an explicit loops by using `sapply`. This (should) avoid any pitfalls of growing vectors

```
results <- sapply(1:5, function(i) { i + 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Now frankly, there must be a better solution than this

```
loopee <- function(x){
  res <- vector(mode = "numeric", length(x))
  for (i in 1:x) {res[i] <- i+1}
  return(res)}

> loopee(5)
[1] 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: See my answer. Yes there is.